# Gmaps4rails - Address language - Brazil to Brasil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Does anyone has a problem with Gmaps4rails address language?

I'm getting the address in english language, but I need it in portuguese. Like Brasil instead Brazil.

I have set some language options (language: 'pt-BR'), but didn't work.

Comment: where did you put this option?

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: In gmaps4rails.base.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, do:

```
acts_as_gmappable :language => 'pt-BR'
```

all available languages [are specified in the doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Comment: did you reload your server?

Comment: Yes @apneadiving. I did.

Comment: I did exactly the same but when I type some address, it's completed with an address in english, as I said, Brazil...

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: ok, and did you create a new model to check? what did you do to test?

Comment: I put that line in the model that uses gmaps4rails.

Comment: you say the address still is in english, but how did you test?

Comment: I'm testing with a text auto complete input.

Comment: I dont understand what you do but I'm pretty confident I gave you the proper answer

Comment: Ok. I'm gonna try do do some others tests and I give you a feedback.
I really appreciate your help.
Thank you, brother!